# Prism Inject XAML UnitValueConverter with additional attributes

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, mvvm, prism

I'm currently implementing a Xamarin MVVM app using Prism.
I have the following IValueConverter:

```
public class MyConverter: IValueConverter, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private readonly IMyInjectedService _myInjectedService;

  public UnitVisualizationConverter(IMyInjectedService myInjectedService)
  {
     _myInjectedService = myInjectedService;
  }

  private string _myProperty= null;

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  public string MyProperty
  {
    get => _myProperty;
    set 
    { 
      _unit = _myProperty; 
      OnPropertyChanged(); 
    }
  }

  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
  {
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
      PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }


  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    //some code
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    // some code
  }
}
```

I was using the following XAML-Code to get the converter into my view and inject `MyInjectedService`:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
  <ioc:ContainerProvider x:TypeArguments="valueConverters:MyConverter"
    x:Key="MyConverter"
    MyProperty ="{Binding DataContext.MyProperty}"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

So I like to bind the value of `MyProperty` to a coresponding value in my ViewModel.
When implementing this I got the error message:
`` The property 'MyProperty' was not found in type 'ContainerProvider`1' ``.
Is there a solution for this problem?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution by myself.
I changed the constructors of the value converter to:

```
 public UnitVisualizationConverter(IMyInjectedService myInjectedService)
{
  _myInjectedService = myInjectedService;
}
public UnitVisualizationConverter(): this(App.ContainerProvider.Resolve<IMyInjectedService>())
{
}
```

So I can use the "normal" XAML declaration of the converter.

```
<myPrefix:MyConverter x:Key="myConverter" MyProperty="{Binding... }"/>
```

A requirement for this solution is that the Prism ContainerProvider is declared public and static.